# Keyword synchronized and synchronization conception

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've been studying Concurrency in Java, I haven't seen relation between the keyword synchronized and the synchronization conception.

For the sake of explanation take it

```
public class MyClass {

  int Counter = 0;

  public synchronized void incrementation(Int newValue){
     Counter += newValue;
  }

}
```

If I'm granting access to one Thread each time in the method incrementation, where's the synchronization?

Comment: The synchronization if being performed by the JVM or by code generated by the JVM.  Can you clarify what your doubt is?

Comment: [Java synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Comment: Note that synchronization when you use `synchronized` keyword happens only within the same instance.

Comment: Not clear why people are downvoting this.  It's a perfectly legitimate question for someone trying to understand concurrency in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `synchronized` keyword in the signature of your function allows only one thread to run the function at a time.  This synchronizes multithreaded access to the `Counter` variable.

In this particular case, the increment of `Counter` is, in machine code, likely implemented as a read of the value from memory to a processor register, an increment of the number in the processor register, and a write of the incremented value back to memory.  Without synchronization, two threads running on different processors could do this at the same time, reading the same value from memory, each incrementing that value in their respective processors, and both writing the same incremented value back to memory.  That would result in an increment of only 1 in memory, despite the fact that two threads had actually incremented the value.  Using the `synchronized` keyword ensures that the threads access the memory value sequentially; if two threads try to do the increment at the same time, they take turns, and the ultimate value in memory ends up incremented twice to reflect the number of threads that incremented the value.

Comment: My confusion wasn't about the proposal of this resource. I was looking for a logic to the name "synchronized" as long as each time a Thread enter into this method it locks that until "complete the job".  I wasn't see a good reason to call this block as "synchronized", provided that just one Thread use it on each occasion.

Comment: Thinking about this question, I've realized that, provided that one or more Threads can use this block of code, we have a good reason to call it as "synchronized". If I'm wrong, please, correct me.